# Easiest way to create a custom linux distribution

Tags: linux, creation, live-cd

Can someone guide me how I can create a custom linux system in the easiest way? I would like to add programs and libraries of my choice on top of a base platform and offer it for free for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between starting your distro vs. using libs/apps you need on top of base platform.

For the later look at [gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/), [archlinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) or [lfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). The first two provide you a bare minimum 50mB core and a solid package manager. Then you can add apps of your choice on top of it. With gentoo you can also compile each of your package with your preffered choice of compile options.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Linux From Scratch http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/. You can build a system from the ground up, including install images. You'll learn a lot about linux too, although it's not a weekend project. Or you could start with a distro such as Debian http://www.debian.org/ which will give you a base system to build on (Ubuntu is based on Debian for example). This is probably a "quicker" option, but still not a small job I'd imagine.

Or alternatively, check these [search results](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=build+your+own+linux+distro) for other options.